# Performance Monitor - Win2k3 - Run as Other User

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance-monitoring

I saw a post where a user was allowed to actively log in and run PerfMon. Is there a way to set it up where I can create a dummy user, tell the Counter Log to run as the user, and tell it to go? Or does someone actively have to be logged in and running PerfMon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your trying to achieve.

If you want an interactive logon from a non-privileged user, then you just have to allow the user to log in, either by adding them to the remote desktop users group, or by updating the local security policy and granting that user the log on locally privilege.

Alternatively, if you are just trying to capture perfmon stats, then simply log in as an administrative user to the server, set up the counter log, start it collecting, and log off the machine.  It will continue to collect in the background.

Comment: The second option is what I want to achieve. When I tried that yesterday, it looked like it had stopped logging when I logged off. I probably just misread the logs. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing that would cause it to stop is if you set a stop time in the options. But from memory the default is for the start and stop to be set to manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the runas command in a script to accomplish this if you really want to.  [The arguments for the command are here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try a remote interactive session:

http://wiki.imacros.net/How_to_Schedule_a_RemoteInteractive_Session